# Port 6443 connection refused when setting up kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, networking, port, ufw

I am reading the documentation for using kubeadm to set up a Kubernetes cluster. I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on three VMs but am currently only working with one of them before doing the configuration on the other two. I have prepared containerd and disabled swap, but am getting stuck with enabling the required ports. I first configured ufw to only allow incoming traffic from port 22 using the OpenSSH application profile. After reading up on enabling required ports, I have run the commands:

`sudo ufw allow 6443`,
`sudo ufw allow 6443/tcp`, and
`sudo ufw allow 6443/udp`.

When I try using telnet to connect, it fails:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

...and when using the private IP other computers connect to it with:

```
telnet 192.168.50.55 6443
Trying 192.168.50.55...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

If I tell telnet to use port 22, it works just fine:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with the firewall configuration? Or is it another thing?

Thank you for the help,

foxler2010

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Thats because there is no process listening on 6443.you can verify it using `ss -nltp | grep 6443`
- 6443 will be listened by "kube-apiserver" which gets created after you initialize the cluster using  `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.50.55 --pod-network-cidr=<pod cidr>`
- since you have not initialized cluster yet , kube-apiserver wont be running hence the error "connection refused".
- In case if you want to verify that you firewall/ufw settings are done properly in order to accept traffic on port 6443(without installating kubernetes cluster)  then you can try following :

```
1. Install nmap " sudo apt-get install nmap "

2. listen to port 6443 "nc -l 6443"

3. open a another terminal/window and connect to 6443 port "nc -zv 192.168.50.55 6443" . It should say connected.
```

Answer (score 4):

Should you check if the kubernetes has run on or not?
Try command:

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

If not, you have to initialize the master node of kubernetes with the command:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.50.55 --pod-network-cidr=10.123.0.0/16
```

192.168.50.55: `IP` of the master node
10.123.0.0/16: `IP` range of network-plugin for kubernetes

Comment: For me, `kubectl cluster-info` looked good, but `systemctl status k3s.service` showed a problem that made my K3s startup fail.

Comment: adding --apiserver-advertise-address works for me and correctly use IP and IP range :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The connection refused typically means that that the request reaches the server but there is no service running on the specified port. Are you sure the api-server is started on your node ?

Comment: I did not do anything with kubeadm, I have only installed containerd so far. Am I not able to test it until the cluster is set up?

Comment: Yes, exactly. . you have installed containerd but you need to run the kube-apiserver to be able to communicate with your cluster . This can be done using kubeadm init . https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#initializing-your-control-plane-node

Answer (score 1):

`I did not do anything with kubeadm, I have only installed containerd so far.`

Do the 6443 test **after** you have ran kubeadm to setup k8s. If you do it now you will not get any response.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time setting up a kubernetes cluster, in the end it was a cgroup driver/version problem.

Basically a mismatch between containerd and kubelet which led kubelet to kill legitimate pods.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74695838/9036077

Comment: This problem still exists on Debian 12. You saved my day!